# Explode JSON in PysparkSQL

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to explode a nested json to CSV file.
Looking to parse the nested json into rows and columns.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Row
df=spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("sample1.json")
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- pid: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Vendor: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RC: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Updated_From_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Updated_To_Date: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- RD: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Supplier: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Supplier_Data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Days: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Reference: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Expected: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Payments: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Approval: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- ID: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Areas_Changed: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Alternate_Names: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Attachments: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Classifications: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Contact_Information: long (nullable = true)
```

My Code:

```
df2=(df.select(F.explode("pid").alias('pid'))
         .select('pid.*')
         .select(F.explode('Body').alias('Body'))
         .select('Body.*')
         .select((F.explode('Vendor').alias('Vendor'))
         .select('Vendor.*')
         .select((F.explode('RC').alias('RC'))
         .select('RC.*'))))
```

Error:
*AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(pid)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<Body:struct< .....*

How can I parse into struct fields.
any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `explode` function only on map or array type. To access strcut type just use `.` operator.

Let's say you want to get columns under RC and RD then code syntax should be as shown below.

```
df.select("pid.Body.Vendor.RC.*", "pid.Body.Vendor.RD.*")
```

Comment: This worked for me but can you suggest me how can I have separate column name for array. For Eg, RD.Supplier.Supplier_Data.Reference.ID  in this case if 2 elements are there then how to separate them into 2 different columns?-Thanks :)

Comment: Let's say array column ID as has 2 elements you want to create 2 different columns then you can do that using array index. `df.selectExpr("RD.Supplier.Supplier_Data.Reference.ID[0] as array1","RD.Supplier.Supplier_Data.Reference.ID[1] as array2")` or `df.select(col("RD.Supplier.Supplier_Data.Reference.ID").getItem(0).as("array1"))`